# bootstrap3 typeahead keydown , keyup makes the selected item disappear

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

I am using the bootstrap3 typeahead but menu is not changing using the keyboard keyup & keydown , so I saw some suggestion about adding :

```
this.$menu.animate({scrollTop: prev.position().top }, 0);
```

I also added another line for next , now the menu is working using the keyup and keydown but the selected item disappears after clicking 3 or 4 times , it is still selected but not visible in the dropdown

[image]